# Audio IN over USB on STM32F4

Tags: audio, interface, usb, stm32

I try to create a simple USB audio interface with audio IN and OUT on a custom board based on an **STM32F412**. The audio OUT (from host to target) is working, also with the help of the CubeMX setup for the audio device usb class. But somehow I can't figure out how the opposite way (from target to host) should work.

I see for audio out, `AUDIO_PeriodicTC_FS` gets called periodically (every 1ms) with the `AUDIO_OUT_TC` command. It never gets called with `AUDIO_IN_TC`. I tried to call `HAL_PCD_EP_Transmit` with some audio data, but the host doesn't get the input...

The descriptor should be right, at least I see both interfaces (in and out) show up on the host.

Is someone experienced in this or can provide some working examples?

Comment: A code snippet is always useful for anyone looking at the question

Comment: (Quite a bit of STM32 questions go "unanswered" here.)

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-usb-audio.html). Used and verified. It works. It may need some deeper modification if your chip doesn't have USB OTG

Comment: Thanks, I implemented the library now (for the second time).
Audio OUT is working as expected (Host to device).
But still Audio IN doesn't deliver any data. I fill the data in `AUDIO_MicHandler->buf->data` but I don't get how to signal to host that there is new data?

Comment: If youo use AUDIO IMPLICIT SYNCHRONIZATION (read you syncronize your samples with USB SOF you receive) you should call AUDIO_MicHandler->node.session_handle->SessionCallback. The examples works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Ive created a simple USB headset on my stm32f4 discovery board. You can check it out, if you're interested:

https://github.com/ancher-bohdan/stm32_usb_interface

It is far from ideal, but it can play music from host and send recorded sound from analog mic to host